# How to make variable width histogram in R with labels aligned to bin edges?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2`, which by default creates histograms with fixed bin widths and whose bin labels are plotted in the center of each bin.

What I want instead is a variable-width histogram whose bin labels are representative of the end points of each bin, like this plot:

[image: desired plot]

To produce this example plot, I manually entered the bin parameters and shifted the bins to align them with their end points:

```
income=data.frame(lx=c(0,10,25,50,100),rx=c(10,25,50,100,150),y=c(20,28,27,18,7))
income$width = income$rx-income$lx


ggplot(income, aes(lx+width/2,y/width)) + geom_bar(aes(width=rx-lx), color='black', stat='identity') + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(c(income$lx,income$rx))) + labs(x='Income (thousands of $)', y='% per thousand $')
```

But I want to do this automatically, from the original data.  (The original data can be approximated using the following code):

```
incomes=unlist(sapply(1:nrow(income), function(i) sample(income$lx[i]:(income$rx[i]-1),income$y[i],replace=TRUE)))
widths=unlist(sapply(1:nrow(income), function(i) rep(income$rx[i]-income$lx[i],income$y[i])))
incomes=data.frame(incomes, widths)
```

Comment: You're talking about the 10, 25, 50, etc labels? But when I run this code in R the results looks the same as your desired histogram?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sort of solution you are looking for? Your code as given creates the desired effect without modification.

Comment: I want to do this automatically, using the original data (see the 'incomes' data frame).  My example was a hand-coded representation of the bins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce a variable width histogram by specifying the desired `breaks` in `geom_histogram`. Use `y=..density..` (rather than the default, which is based on counts), so that the bars will be normalized to their proportion of the total bar area.

```
breaks = c(0,10,25,50,100,150)

ggplot(incomes, aes(incomes)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                 color="black", fill="grey40", breaks=breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks)
```

[image]