# combining Histogram bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram using basic R. The histogram is doing a good job representing the data. However, I want to combine the few bars on the right-side(from 300,000+)( here is an image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMtre.png)) into one bar to represent their values.

```
hist(TotalIncomeRural$D21, breaks ="sturges", labels = TRUE,
       xaxt='n', ylim=c(0,1350), col = "red")
axis(side=1, at=c(seq(0,1500000,100000)))
```

any help is very much appreciated.

Edit:
I'll demonstrate what I want to do with the histogram:
suppose I have this data and hist function:

```
x<-c(1,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,13,15,1,3,8,10,1,6,8,2,0, 2,5,3,8,5,5,1,0,0,0,0,3,6,5,8,10,12,16,18, 9, 8,1,1,1,0,5,5,5,6)
hist(x)
```

when I run this new histogram I'd like to combine all the values above 10 into one bin to represent them (I'm attaching an image here).

[image]

Comment: Hi j_sands. It's always better to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) that way you can help others to help you!
Also I am not sure if I understand your question: Do you want to have bins that have different sizes?

Comment: Possibly useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37766893

Comment: Though the other answer demonstrated some new features for you, did you try just `hist(x, breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20))`? It gives (I think) precisely what you show in your drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the breaks and axis labels:

```
hist( TotalIncomeRural$D21, 
      breaks = c(0:3, 16) * 100000,
      ylim = c(0, 1350),
      xlim = c(0, 400000),
      freq = T,
      xaxt = "n",
      col = "red")

axis( side = 1, 
      at = (0:3 +.5) * 100000, 
      tick = F,
      labels = c("\n< $100,000\n ", 
                 "\n$100,000 -\n$200,000", 
                 "\n$200,000 -\n$300,000", 
                 "\n> $300,000\n "))
```

[image]

I tried to mimic your original data like this:

```
set.seed(69)
TotalIncomeRural <- data.frame(D21 = rexp(2000)^1.3 * 100000)
```

If you wanted to, you could have one big wide bar at the right by changing the `xlim` of the axis, but then the labels wouldn't fit as well (and the area of the histogram would be wrong)

Comment: could you briefly explain how  (breaks = c(0:3, 16) * 100000,) works?

Comment: especially, why you used 16? so I can use it when i create other histograms. thank you

Comment: @j_sands That was just so all my random data fitted in. The expression c(0:3, 16) * 100000 expands to (0, 100000, 200000, 300000, 1600000), which means that's where the breaks were. The highest number in my random data was about 1530000, so I just needed to make sure the highest break was higher than that.